# Ternary IF causes out of memory

Tags: php, memory-leaks, ternary-operator

I have come across something a little odd. I as trying to use the following ternary if statement:

```
$output .= ($row['creditUsed'] > $row['creditLimit'] ? 'color:red;' : $output) ;
```

Which caused my browser to hang and eventually end up with a PHP out of memory error.

For now I am simply using:

```
if($row['creditUsed'] > $row['creditLimit'])
{
    $output .= 'color:red;' ;
}
```

Which works fine.

Does anyone know why this would happen? The if statement is in a while loop, the full code is too much to post:

```
$i = 0 ;
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

if($i == 0)
{
    //something
}
if($row['amountDue'] > $row['amount'] && $row['amount'] > 0.01)
{
// Stuff
}
else
{
    $output .= ($row['creditUsed'] > $row['creditLimit'] ? 'color:red;' : $output) ;
}
$i++ ;
}
```

---

It's my mistake! I realise that $output is getting exponentially bigger every iteration of the loop. I changed it to:
$output .= ($row['creditUsed'] > $row['creditLimit'] ? 'color:red;' : '') ;

And it's fine.

Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're repeatedly appending `$output` to itself (if the condition fails), causing it to double in size (i.e. exponential growth) on each iteration.

If you really must use the ternary operator here, you need to append an *empty* string in the third operand, not the original string:

```
$output .= ($row['creditUsed'] > $row['creditLimit'] ? 'color:red;' : '');
```

Comment: Edited just as you answered. Will accept yours as the answer though :)